# I can no longer run sudo commands - password not accepted

Tags: sudo, password

I have a server running Ubuntu which has been online for over a year. I connect to the server through SSH using my own user (not root) and using SSH keys (passwordless login). This user is part of the sudoers and I regularly run commands using `su`. This has worked well since the beginning. My user password is saved in a password manager - I never enter anything manually.

Since earlier this month my password is no longer accepter. When I try to run:

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for my_user:
Sorry, try again.
```

And after 3 tries:

```
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

The password did not change. I am pasting the right password. I even tried manually copying the password from the password manager. So something else is up.

I have checked that I am still part of the sudoers group. I have checked that the drive is not full or the CPU is overloaded. Nothing is out of the ordinary. I do run automatic updates so there WAS new software installed simply by virtue of running the auto updating scripts for Ubuntu Server. Running Ubuntu 22.04.

When I try to change my own user's password by running:

```
$ passwd my_user
Changing password for my_user.
Current password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

So the problem is not with sudo itself but with my user authentication, it seems.

Given that I can't run anything as root, I can't check everything that I would want to.

I did check some more things as per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/107386/trying-to-change-a-ubuntu-users-password-authentication-token-manipulation-err), including:

- Filesystem is NOT mounted read-only according to `/proc/mounts`
- `/etc/shadow` has permissions `-rw-r-----` and is owned by `root:shadow`

Output of sudo -l:

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for my_user on lla_server:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User my_user may run the following commands on lla_server:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

---

```
$ grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         compat systemd
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sudo
#%PAM-1.0

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required   pam_limits.so

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sudo-i
#%PAM-1.0

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required   pam_limits.so

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

---

```
$ su - my_user
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/common-auth
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

What are things I can check, or what could cause this issue? Remember I can't do anything as root, so I can't check e.g. `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: Please run `sudo -l` and add the output of this command to your question.

Comment: I have added that output @aviro, thanks

Comment: On a *default* Ubuntu installation, you should be able to read /var/log/auth.log provided you are a member of the `adm` group

Comment: Please also add the output of `grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf`, and the content of `/etc/pam.d/sudo` (and `/etc/pam.d/sudo-i`, if you have it). And last thing, when you run `su - my_user`, does it accept your password?

Comment: @aviro I added the requested output. `su - my_user` does not accept my password either

Comment: @steeldriver I am unfortunately not part of the `adm` group...

Comment: `su` does not expect _your_ password, but the password of the root account.

Comment: Ahhh I see @Kusalananda but unfortunately I am not sure about that password - I have never needed it.

Comment: The contents of `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` might be helpful (especially as the issue appears to apply beyond sudo)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver I have added this

Comment: Thanks - so (aside from some whitespace differences - which may be due to the site's formatting) that looks identical to the default.

Comment: Anyway, whatever the problem is, I'm pretty sure it will require root privileges to fix it.

Comment: Makes sense @steeldriver - I haven't made any changes myself.

Comment: @Kusalananda `su` expects that password of the user that you are switching to. For `su - my_user`, it does NOT expect the password of `root` but `my_user`.

Comment: @T_M100 Maybe you should try `passwd my_user` again while having `journalctl -kf` running and see if there's actually some kind of I/O error. Could be due to a dying drive, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @TomYan but no output whatsoever in `journalctl -kf` when I try changing the password.

Comment: @T_M100 hmm, do you mean like there's no output at all if you run `journalctl -k`? In that case it would mean that in your system you can't read kernel messages with that (at least not with a user without corresponding privilege).

Comment: @TomYan I see a message saying "You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system. Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages." But then it pauses and shows me the potential output (and I assume that new logs would be printed right there, but nothing appears as I run the passwd command)

Comment: @TomYan So it is. I obviously did not read the whole way down. All examples of the use of `sudo` in the question are related to acquiring root privileges, though. So it seems strange that they want to use `su` to log in as the user they are already logged in as (assuming `my_user` is the current user, which the OP says nothing about).

Comment: Check if you are actually the user you think you are. Try `echo $USER` and `whoami` (maybe you `su`'d into a different account). If possible, try rebooting the server. When was `/etc/passwd` last modified? Is this before or after `sudo` stopped working? Can you provide command `history`?

Comment: @wjwrpoyob my user is why I think I am. Server is a live production server, cannot be restarted. Last change of `/etc/passwd` is from before this problem (dates back to last year). No relevant commands appear in my user's history.